# Micro-USB B - female weird pinout

Tags: pcb, usb, soldering, repair, hobbyist

fixing up a kids toy today that used a USB Micro-B cable/port. The female port was smashed up.

I have started to remove the old female socket and noticed it did not use a standard pin out. Rather than have the 5 pins in one horizontal line they have them on two rows.

Because the old port was severely damaged I am having difficultly identifying the pins and I can't really find anything online.

Could somebody help me identify which pins are +5v and ground?

[image: red box where old port was]

Comment: See if this sheds any light on it for you

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/usb-connectors/1225097/

Comment: thanks so much! i literally spent an hour on that website looking at all the connectors! that looks like the one that was on there

Comment: ;)     I've done this before    LOL      The keyword search I used was "vertical through hole micro USB B female jack", then looked at the images on Google.

Comment: BTW, clearing those holes is not gonna be easy, specifically 'cuz that solder is sure to be 'lead free'.  I would fill the holes with standard lead-based solder first, then use a piece of thin solder wick to pull the whole glob out.  Practice on some scrap boards first.  One or two of the holes (power and ground) will be extra difficult if there are 'planes' of copper connecting them as they'll sink heat away.